# Determine GroupBox when event sender is GroupBox content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a groupbox with the content set to a canvas which I create (both) at runtime.
When an onclick event is called and the sender = the canvas how do I get groupbox?

I am trying to get the vector for a drag+drop thing I am doing but the following does NOT work.

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(parent);
```

I think this does not work because the groupbox is not the parent of the canvas, but rather the canvas is the CONTENT of the groupbox.

```
groupbox1.Content = canvas1;
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: More code please. It's kinda hard without knowing your XAML